# VALIDACION CAMBIO DE TABLAS LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Tengo una consulta en Linq bastante grande pero necesito que dependiendo de que rol tenga el usuario me haga la consulta a una tabla u otra , las tablas son idénticas en estructura, solo cambia el nombre de la tabla, cómo puedo validar eso sin necesidad de copiar toda la consulta meterla en un if y solo cambiar el nombre de la tabla adjunto ejemplo de lo que probé:

```
var Tabla = "";

if(Rol == "Rol1")
{
    Tabla = "Productos1";
}
else
{
    Tabla = "Productos2";
}

var productos = await db.Set<Tabla>().toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 2 tablas iguales, por lo que en teoría deberías tener **una sola clase** que representa ambas tablas. Esto trae algunos problemas en Entity Framework, por lo que la solución es crear una clase padre y 2 clases hijas que deberiben de ella, estas 2 clases estarán vacias.

```
public abstract class Producto //clase padre
{
   //las propiedades
}
public class Producto1 : Producto {} //clase sin nada dentro
public class Producto2 : Producto {} //clase sin nada dentro
```

Luego para usar `Producto1` o `Producto2`, debes castearlo a `Producto`

```
var producto = Rol == "Rol1" ? db.Producto1s.Cast<Producto>() : db.Producto2s.Cast<Producto>()
```